# Are the scenes in the opening theme content from later episodes?

Tags: anime-production, one-piece

The episode 629 of *One Piece* is out with a new opening theme. The opening shows scenes from dressrosa arc ( which I have read in manga ) which will be covered in the future episodes ( in the range of 30-40 future episodes ).

Are these episodes have already been produced and scenes cut from these episodes are used in the opening or are these short scenes are made just for the opening theme?

If future episodes are produced before hand then roughly how many episodes are produced in advance?

Comment: i don't think anyone can really answer this. It depends on the animation company! Good question though!
This is not a case with One Piece only. You'd see this in many other anime's too. For example naruto or even fairy tail. They normally add scenes from future episodes in the present openings. That's what i believe after seeing so much anime :P

Comment: I think this also is a bit dependant on the producer. If also seen plenty of anime that also showed future events in openings. and never continued, or came to that point in time .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the OP and ED are handled separately (sometimes by different studio). The studio/team that created the OP/ED are [usually credited](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=KttpUvA4eoA#t=76).

The animated content in the OP and ED are usually done exclusively for their respective themes. Sometimes you'll notice stylistic differences between the animated content of the OP/ED and that of the actual show.

When anime is localized sometimes the licensor doesn't have access tp (or chooses not to pay for) the original creditless OP/ED themes so they remix the opening and add their own soundtracks to it. Sometimes to better fit their target audience (in regards to the language) and probably at same time not have to pay to license the songs and/or edited to fit within their broadcasting lot (i.e. more commercial time).